# jsPlumb edit position of endpoint

Tags: location, endpoint, jsplumb

Working with projects with jsPlumb I set static connector to two map markers. the end points of the jsplumb connector appear above the map marker image while I want these to appear below.

from where, in the jsplumb javascript library, do I edit the calculated position of the endpoints?

Answer (score 4):

One way to set endpoint anchor position is using the jsPlumb defaults as:

```
jsPlumb.importDefaults({
    PaintStyle : {lineWidth:1,strokeStyle:color2},
    Connector: ["Straight"],
    Anchor:"Continuous" // dymamically nearest position will be considered for endpoint
    //OR
    Anchor:["Top","Bottom"] // only top or bottom center whichever is near will be considered as endpoints
    //OR
    Anchor:["Left","Right"] // similarly left or right center will be considered
});
```

Can also declare at the time of connecting as:

```
jsPlumb.connect({
     source:someDiv,
     target:someOtherDiv,
     anchors:["Bottom", "Continuous"] // Bottom nearest point will be considered
});
```

For makeTarget and makeSource declare it as:

```
jsPlumb.makeSource(someDiv, {
     anchor:"Continuous",
     paintStyle:{ fillStyle:"red" }
});
```

Or at the time of adding endpoint declare as:

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint(someDiv, {
     anchor:"Continuous",
     paintStyle:{ fillStyle:"red" }
 });
```